# How to create registry entries using squirrel.windows

Tags: javascript, electron, squirrel.windows

I am creating an Electron application, and am using electron-winstaller to build the installer, which uses squirrel.windows.   Inside of one of the example code snippets has this section:

```
const squirrelEvent = process.argv[1];
switch (squirrelEvent) {
  case '--squirrel-install':
  case '--squirrel-updated':
    // Optionally do things such as:
    // - Add your .exe to the PATH
    // - Write to the registry for things like file associations and
    // explorer context menus

    // Install desktop and start menu shortcuts
    spawnUpdate(['--createShortcut', exeName]);

    setTimeout(app.quit, 1000);
    return true;

  case '--squirrel-uninstall':
    // Undo anything you did in the --squirrel-install and
    // --squirrel-updated handlers

    // Remove desktop and start menu shortcuts
    spawnUpdate(['--removeShortcut', exeName]);

    setTimeout(app.quit, 1000);
    return true;

  case '--squirrel-obsolete':
    // This is called on the outgoing version of your app before
    // we update to the new version - it's the opposite of
    // --squirrel-updated

    app.quit();
    return true;
  }
}
```

In the section above that says "- Write to the registry for things like file associations and explorer context menus.".   I would like to add registry entries here, but when looking at the squirrel documentation I could not figure how to do this. I could not find any examples online.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any solution for this question ?

Comment: Same here... I'm building an kiosk app and I need to disable the Windows 10 lateral swipe events. I think I can do it adding an registry key to disable that feature, but I don't know how can I write the values to registry in the '--squirrel-install' and '--squirrel-updated'  events, inside that script.

Did you found a way?

Answer (score 0):

Squirrel does not expose commands to change registry, so you would have to write your own. An example is `spawnReg` in this CoffeeScript: https://gist.github.com/Hrxn/7f415e5e32abb83eff27